# Are "act quickly" and "gives you" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality

Is it correct to use "act quickly" and "gives you" in the following sentence?

> Xpto tracks xyz bounces. It gives you real-time statistics and details so you can act quickly.

Comment: [Related.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23838/is-this-phrase-grammatically-correct) @donald, you can edit your older question instead of creating a new one. Questions can be reopened if the edit fixes whatever caused it to be closed.

Answer (score 2):

So far as translations into idiomatic English go, that's not bad at all. For American English, anyway, it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's reasonable in a grammatic sense, but a couple of synonyms might better convey your message. Maybe something like:

> It *provides* real-time statistics
>   allowing you to *respond rapidly* to
>   [insert whatever you're responding to].

Comment: "Provides" is a better choice, but the verb is so overused in technical documentation I'd prefer to read almost anything else that's close.

Comment: Fair point @mfe.

Answer (score 0):

I think that everything in the sentence you stated you is grammatically correct.

However, I think you could reduce it to one sentence if you are interested.

> Xpto tracks xyz bounces, and provides real-time statistics and details so you can act quickly.